# Is there any way to share screen of one ios device to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, alljoyn

Is there any way to share Ipad screen to another Ipad , like skype screen sharing ?
I tried by capturing the screenshot per second and send the screenshot to anoher device using Alljoyn Framework.
Its working but when application is in background it doesn't work because image capturing code not work in Background it will crash the application.

Is there any library or framework ? Please help .

Comment: if application is in background, GUI won't be updating anyways? So why not just screen share while in foreground, then stop screen share when entering background?

Comment: Yes thats what I am doing but its the requirement? What to do ?

Comment: Then just display the last shown screen before pause. Or do you actually want to show the homescreen and all?

Comment: Yes , I need to show whatever user do on other Ipad , its for teacher to get his eye on student what he is doing in his Ipad.

Comment: No, not possible unless they are in the same room then just use airplay

Comment: Is there any Api for Airplay to share screen among the same WIFI Network ?

Comment: Hi ManiaChamp, Can you please share you screen sharing code. I want to work on that now... I did screen sharing using Team viewer and Skreen me, they from mobile to browser. I need to share my iOS to another iOS device.. It will be very helpful if you share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. iOS applications cannot view or control the display while in the background.

Comment: Ok Thanks ! For Foreground is there any other better approach to share screen?